Prove that $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly dependent if and only if $span(S_1) \cap span(S_2) \neq \{0\}$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are linearly independent.
Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be disjoint linearly independent subsets of $V$. Prove that $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly dependent if and only if $\text{Span}(S_1) \cap \text{Span}(S_2) \neq \{0\}$.
The official answer is given in https://media.pearsoncmg.com/aw/aw_friedberg_linearalgebra_5e/solutions/sec_1_5.html
For the first direction, I get that since $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly dependent, then there must some non-zero scalars such that
$$a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + ... + a_nu_n + b_1w_1 + b_2w_2 + ... + b_nw_m = \bar{0}$$
But then the claim is that if since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are linearly independent, then
$$a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + ... + a_nu_n = -(b_1w_1 + b_2w_2 + ... + b_nw_m) = w$$
is a non-zero vector.
I don't understand how we used the linear independence of $S_1$ and $S_2$ to declare that $w$ must be non-zero. I do understand that

some of the scalars are non-zero because the union is linearly dependent.
$a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + ... + a_nu_n$ is in $\text{Span}(S_1)$
$-(b_1w_1 + b_2w_2 + ... + b_nw_m)$ is in $\text{Span}(S_2)$

Couldn't the scalars $a_1, a_2,...a_n$ be possibly all zeros while all the $b$s are non-zero?
Thanks!

If all $a_i$s are zero, then all $b_i$s are zero since $S_2$ is linearly independent!

The vector $w$ must be indeed be nonzero if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are linearly independent.

Indeed, as already noted, to start with, if $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly dependent, then either at least one of $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_n$ must be nonzero or at least one of $b_1,b_2, \ldots, b_n$ must be nonzero, say WLOG at least one of $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ is nonzero, by definition of linear dependence of $S_1 \cup S_2$.

But then by definition of linear independence of $S_1$ then, the vector $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i = w$ must be nonzero.

But then as $w$ $\in$ span$(S_1)$ is nonzero and $\sum_{i=1}^n b_iv_i = -w$, we can conclude that $w$ ins in span$(S_2)$ as well and so $w$ is in span$(S_1) \cap$span$(S_2)$. [And furthermore, at least one of $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ must be nonzero as well, zero vectors cannot sum to a nonzero vector.]


So given that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are each linearly independent: Then you have just shown that if $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly dependent, then there is a nonzero vector $w$ in both span$(S_1)$ and in span$(S_2)$. Equivalently, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are each linearly independent and span$(S_1)$ and span$(S_2)$ do not intersect nontrivially, then $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly independent.  That is one direction. Note however: If either $S_1$ or $S_2$ are linearly dependent, then so is $S_1 \cup S_2$ whether the spans intersect nontrivially or not.
Of course, to show the other direction, this proof works the other way: If there is a nonzero vector $w$ in span$(S_1) \cap$ span$(S_2)$, then $S_1 \cup S_2$ is linearly dependent. Indeed, first write $w=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i$ and
then $-w=\sum_{i=1}^n b_iv_i$. As $w$ is nonzero, at least one of $a_1,a_2, \ldots a_n$ is nonzero and so is at least one of $b_1,b_2, \ldots, b_n$ is nonzero. But then what is $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i$ $+$ $\sum_{i=1}^n b_iv_i$? Isn't this sum $0$? Note that this other direction doesn't care about the linear independence of $S_1$ or $S_2$.
